# Attribute for tagging MSIL section

Tags: c#, attributes, cil

Is there a mechanism for tagging a spot in code that will carry that tag into the generated MSIL?

It would be helpful when looking for a particular part of a large method, rather than having to read through all the MSIL to find the section you want.

Currently, I just put an unreferenced string variable. That will show up in a debug build but not a production build, but it's a hack and I hoped there might be a proper way. Like maybe a compiler attribute or something, but I cannot find anything.

Per first comment, adding more details... This is a section of MSIL for a large method. It correlates to a line of C# code for which I want to see the generated MSIL:

- ...
- IL_0645:  stloc.s    nLon
- IL_0647:  ldloc.s    ofs
- IL_0649:  ldarg.1
- IL_064a:  bge.s      IL_0660
- IL_064c:  ldloc.0
- IL_064d:  ldloc.s    ofs
- IL_064f:  dup
- IL_0650:  ldc.i4.1
- IL_0651:  add
- IL_0652:  stloc.s    ofs
- IL_0654:  conv.i
- IL_0655:  ldc.i4.2
- IL_0656:  mul
- IL_0657:  add
- IL_0658:  ldind.u2
- IL_0659:  dup
- ...

My question is is there a simple way to find this section, via annotation or ??, other than reading from IL_0000 and following down 600+ lines of MSIL codes.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. What you asking for is unclear. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Personally, I don't understand the question, and the BR.S (x86 JMP) mention for a tag... but I'm poor in english. Using ILSpy or Reflector, for example, you can see both C# and generated IL, so you can easily read the code, isn't it ?

Comment: I saw the updated question. If I understand, you can't. You got generated IL for every C# line of code, hence as many IL atom instruction as required. You can't put something between. All you can do is to set both C# and IL for the disassembler tool, and let your eyes discriminate the listing. Also you can refactor your code to create smaller methods and you will have more clean code, better designed and maintanable.

Comment: I did not expect Stackoverflow to be such a hostile site. You actually **downvoted** me because you didn't understand my question? That's pretty insulting. Not everyone is an expert in everything, which is why they come here to ask questions. My edits (adding example CIL, which are not actually pertinent to the question) really did nothing to enhance the question itself. The question only required reading the first 2 paragraphs. And the 3rd was a workaround I use, which adds context. My question can't be more specific when looking for something I don't know.

Comment: @.user6604437 I'm not trying to be hostile. I hope I have been the opposite of hostile here trying to help you. I took time to try to understand and help you. But I think the question is too esoteric and has no value to be keeped on SO, so the downvote. Don't be mad at me, downvotes are for that, whatever I may be wrong or not. If you or someone convinces me that I am wrong, I will cancel. So the close vote asking for clarification and more details, but you did not answer me... Have a good job!

Comment: Hello @user6604437, how come you cannot simply place this code into a static method and refer to it via the method name? That is probably the best way to do this.

Otherwise, no I don't really see a good way to do this. Unless you can give me a bigger picture of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Whilst I can't think of a supported method, you could make one of your multiplications `checked` which will convert it from a `mul` to ` mul.ovf` instruction in the IL, which ought to be easy to find. This isn't a perfect solution since it may have functional and/or performance impact, but it might be an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a mechanism to insert an attribute directly into the IL stream, unfortunately, but you can "abuse" exception handling to mark a segment of code via try/catch:

```cs
static void MarkedMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("A");
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }catch(Marker)
    {
        throw;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("C");
}

sealed class Marker : Exception
{
    private Marker() { }
}

var body = ((Action)MarkedMethod).Method.GetMethodBody();
foreach(var cl in body.ExceptionHandlingClauses)
{
    if(cl.Flags == ExceptionHandlingClauseOptions.Clause && cl.CatchType.Equals(typeof(Marker)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cl.TryOffset + ", " + cl.TryLength);
    }
}
```

`try` should be pretty lightweight anyway, so assuming the `catch` block is never entered, this shouldn't have much of an impact